# Jackhammers not changing on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the image to change based on one second timer, but the image stays one the first object in the array
the code I have so far is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lab 8 - Jackhammer Man</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var jackhammers = new Array();
 jackhammers[0] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer0.gif'>";
 jackhammers[1] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer1.gif'>";
 jackhammers[2] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer2.gif'>";
 jackhammers[3] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer2.gif'>";
 jackhammers[4] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer4.gif'>";
 jackhammers[5] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer5.gif'>";
 jackhammers[6] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer6.gif'>";
 jackhammers[7] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer7.gif'>";
 jackhammers[8] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer8.gif'>";
 jackhammers[9] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer9.gif'>";
 jackhammers[10] = "<img src='Images/jackhammer10.gif'>";

 var curJackhammer;
 function bounce() {
   var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
   var i = 0 ;

   for (i = 0; i<10;i++) {
      if(jackhammers[i].src == img.src) {
        if(i === jackkhammers.length) {
          img.src = jackhammers[0].src;
          break;
        }
          img.src = jackhammers[i+1].src;
          break;
      } 
   }
 }
</script>
</head>


<body>
<img onMouseOver="setInterval(function(){bounce},1000);" onMouseOut="clearInternval(fuction(){bounce};" src="Images/jackhammer0.gif" id="hammer" name="hammerman" alt="Jackhammer Man">
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm coming across is the mouseover event will not activate, I am having trouble finding the error in my code as the debuggers I have aren't finding any. Any help trying to get the mouseover function of the image changing ever so often would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you actually call `bounce()` ?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn scroll a bit, there's a timeout in the img element.

Comment: Ah, yeah missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you have a typo if(i === jackkhammers.length)
2. jackhammers[x] has no src property so to get its value use it without .src
3. instead of

   onMouseOver="setInterval(function(){bounce},1000);"

write:

```
onMouseOver="setInterval(function(){bounce();},1000);"
```

Comment: or even: `onMouseOver="setInterval(bounce,1000);"`

Comment: This did help fix the issue only problem became the time delay after your help

Answer (score 2):

`var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");`

This returns a NodeList, or an array of elements. You need to access the index of this element with `[0]`

Or better yet, use `querySelector` which returns the first element in a NodeList

Comment: I was told to use document.getElementsByTagName("img") for this particular problem.

Comment: Well then access the index you need, because `Elements` (note the s) implies a list

Answer (score 0):

You keep referring to the `src` property of items in the `jackhammers` array:

```
img.src = jackhammers[0].src;
```

even though items in that array are strings, not objects.

Also, there's a typo here:

```
if(i === jackkhammers.length) {
```

These kinds of errors would be immediately visible the with dev tools of your browser of choise. Put a breakpoint to where you suspect things go wrong and start investigating variables and your assumptions while stepping through the code.

See here: http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820

Comment: The extra k was typed by me when typing in the code here, not in my actual source code next time will just copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

Updated code changed a few things around based on some advice from my mentor.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lab 8 - Jackhammer Man</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var jackhammers = new Array(11);
jackhammers[0] = "Images/jackhammer0.gif";
jackhammers[1] = "Images/jackhammer1.gif";
jackhammers[2] = "Images/jackhammer2.gif";
jackhammers[3] = "Images/jackhammer3.gif";
jackhammers[4] = "Images/jackhammer4.gif";
jackhammers[5] = "Images/jackhammer5.gif";
jackhammers[6] = "Images/jackhammer6.gif";
jackhammers[7] = "Images/jackhammer7.gif";
jackhammers[8] = "Images/jackhammer8.gif";
jackhammers[9] = "Images/jackhammer9.gif";
jackhammers[10] = "Images/jackhammer10.gif";

var curJackhammer = 0;
var direction;
var begin;

function bounce(){

    if(curJackhammer == 10)
        curJackhammer = 0;
    else
        ++curJackhammer;
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = jackhammers[curJackhammer].src;

    if(curJackhammer == 0)
        direction = "up";

    else if(curJackhammer == 10)
        direction = "down";
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = jackhammers[curJackhammer];
}

function startBouncing(){

    if (begin)
        clearInterval (begin);
    begin = setInterval("bounce()",90);
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Jackhammer Man</h1>

<p><img onMouseOver="startBouncing();" onMouseOut="clearInterval(begin);" src="Images/jackhammer0.gif" height="113" width="100" alt="Image of a man with a jackhammer." /></p>
</body>
</html>


>
```

Used firebug to step into code, works once I set into it but simply putting a mouse over nothing happens.